# onScroll() disables mouseenter() on same element

Tags: mouseenter, onscroll

I'm trying to bind two event handlers for the same element but when onScroll() is triggered, mouseenter won't work any reason for that and work around?

```
   var main = function() {
  $(window).scroll(function() {
 if ($(window).scrollTop() > 900) {

$(".swap").delay(900).animate({
        opacity: 1, 
        marginRight: 0
    }, 'slow'
);
 }
  });
 $(".swap").mouseenter(function(){

  $(".swap").fadeOut('fast', function() {
    $(".swap-hidden").fadeIn("slow");
    $(".mobile p").last().append('and tablets')
  });
  });

  };
  $(document).ready(main);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because mouseenter requires the actual page coordinates (x and y) and scrolling changes them dynamically, so you need to rebind (or check for) mouseenter after each scroll event.

Your options are:

1. Switch `mouseenter` with `hover`.
2. Rewrite your function like this (include your mouseenter function into the `document.ready` function:

   ```
   var main = function() {
       $(window).scroll(function() {
           if ($(window).scrollTop() > 900) {
               $(".swap").delay(900).animate({
                   opacity: 1,
                   marginRight: 0
               }, 'slow');
           }
           $(".swap").mouseenter(function() {
               $(".swap").fadeOut('fast', function() {
                   $(".swap-hidden").fadeIn("slow");
                   $(".mobile p").last().append('and tablets')
               });
           });
       };
   });
   $(document).ready(main);
   ```

Comment: So that would mean that after if statement i have to write rebind code and after scroll event same one? Or?

Comment: Hover did the trick, tell me does fade in and fade out slow or fast work with hover?

Comment: They work. I've used this combination hundreds of times.